# Angular JS with Dialog, Tabs and fixed footer

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Having a issue where I'm trying to use Angular Material, Tabs and a Dialog.

What I'm looking for, is to have a dialog with tabs displayed inside. Within that, I want the first tab to fill up 100% of the height (minus the tab header, and a class I added "footer".

Here is a plnkr I started, but am stuck as I can't get the list items to take up all of the height.

[http://plnkr.co/edit/2szJQPaMfXF4utyQO1X1?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/uqjn1f?p=preview)

If you scroll down the list on tab 1, you'll see "Footer", which I would want to not be scrollable at all. That item would be fixed to the bottom of the dialog.

```
<md-dialog aria-label="Mango (Fruit)">
  <md-dialog-content>
    <div class="md-dialog-content">
      <md-tabs>
        <md-tab label="First Tab">
          <md-content flex>
            <md-list flex>
              <md-item ng-repeat="item in items">
                <md-item-content>
                  <div flex class="md-tile-content">
                    {{item}}
                  </div>
                </md-item-content>
                <md-divider></md-divider>
              </md-item>
            </md-list>
          </md-content>
          <div class="footer">
            Footer should be at the bottom
          </div>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="Second tab">
          <md-list flex>
            <md-item ng-repeat="item in items">
              <md-item-content>{{item}}</md-item-content>
            </md-item>
          </md-list>
        </md-tab>
      </md-tabs>
    </div>
  </md-dialog-content>
</md-dialog>
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I have a solution, thought the sticky footer can't be within each tab. While this is somewhat of a dealbreaker, I can work around this and use ng-if to show the sticky footer when need.

If anyone has an answer on how to have the sticky footer within each tab and behave the the way the first tab does, kudos to you and an answer you shall be granted.

http://plnkr.co/edit/6bkgGW?p=preview

```
<md-dialog aria-label="Mango (Fruit)" layout="column" layout-fill>
  <md-dialog-content layout="column" flex>
    <md-tabs layout="column" flex>
        <md-tab label="First Tab">
          <md-content>
            <p>Integer turpis erat, porttitor vitae mi faucibus, laoreet interdum tellus. Curabitur posuere molestie dictum. Morbi eget congue risus, quis rhoncus quam. Suspendisse vitae hendrerit erat, at posuere mi. Cras eu fermentum nunc. Sed id ante eu orci commodo volutpat non ac est. Praesent ligula diam, congue eu enim scelerisque, finibus commodo lectus.</p>
            <p>Integer turpis erat, porttitor vitae mi faucibus, laoreet interdum tellus. Curabitur posuere molestie dictum. Morbi eget congue risus, quis rhoncus quam. Suspendisse vitae hendrerit erat, at posuere mi. Cras eu fermentum nunc. Sed id ante eu orci commodo volutpat non ac est. Praesent ligula diam, congue eu enim scelerisque, finibus commodo lectus.</p>
            <p>Integer turpis erat, porttitor vitae mi faucibus, laoreet interdum tellus. Curabitur posuere molestie dictum. Morbi eget congue risus, quis rhoncus quam. Suspendisse vitae hendrerit erat, at posuere mi. Cras eu fermentum nunc. Sed id ante eu orci commodo volutpat non ac est. Praesent ligula diam, congue eu enim scelerisque, finibus commodo lectus.</p>
            <p>Integer turpis erat, porttitor vitae mi faucibus, laoreet interdum tellus. Curabitur posuere molestie dictum. Morbi eget congue risus, quis rhoncus quam. Suspendisse vitae hendrerit erat, at posuere mi. Cras eu fermentum nunc. Sed id ante eu orci commodo volutpat non ac est. Praesent ligula diam, congue eu enim scelerisque, finibus commodo lectus.</p>
            <p>Integer turpis erat, porttitor vitae mi faucibus, laoreet interdum tellus. Curabitur posuere molestie dictum. Morbi eget congue risus, quis rhoncus quam. Suspendisse vitae hendrerit erat, at posuere mi. Cras eu fermentum nunc. Sed id ante eu orci commodo volutpat non ac est. Praesent ligula diam, congue eu enim scelerisque, finibus commodo lectus.</p>
            <p>Integer turpis erat, porttitor vitae mi faucibus, laoreet interdum tellus. Curabitur posuere molestie dictum. Morbi eget congue risus, quis rhoncus quam. Suspendisse vitae hendrerit erat, at posuere mi. Cras eu fermentum nunc. Sed id ante eu orci commodo volutpat non ac est. Praesent ligula diam, congue eu enim scelerisque, finibus commodo lectus.</p>
            <p>Integer turpis erat, porttitor vitae mi faucibus, laoreet interdum tellus. Curabitur posuere molestie dictum. Morbi eget congue risus, quis rhoncus quam. Suspendisse vitae hendrerit erat, at posuere mi. Cras eu fermentum nunc. Sed id ante eu orci commodo volutpat non ac est. Praesent ligula diam, congue eu enim scelerisque, finibus commodo lectus.</p>
            <p>Integer turpis erat, porttitor vitae mi faucibus, laoreet interdum tellus. Curabitur posuere molestie dictum. Morbi eget congue risus, quis rhoncus quam. Suspendisse vitae hendrerit erat, at posuere mi. Cras eu fermentum nunc. Sed id ante eu orci commodo volutpat non ac est. Praesent ligula diam, congue eu enim scelerisque, finibus commodo lectus.</p>
          </md-content>
          <div class="footer">
            Footer should be at the bottom
          </div>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="Second tab">
          <md-list>
            <md-item ng-repeat="item in items">
              <md-item-content>{{item}}</md-item-content>
            </md-item>
          </md-list>
        </md-tab>
      </md-tabs>
  </md-dialog-content>

  <md-dialog-actions layout="row">
    <md-button ng-click="answer('useful')" style="margin-right:20px;">
      Useful
    </md-button>
  </md-dialog-actions>
</md-dialog>
```